# How to notate rhythmically arpeggiated chord vs arpeggiated melody?

Tags: notation, chords, pop-music

In popular music, sounding a chord with a sort of rhythmic arpeggio is very common, both on piano and on guitar. In Hungarian we have a separate word for it, "akkordbontás". Is there an English term for this, and is there a more readable way to notate it than this?

[image: image example]

Comment: A slow arpeggio?

Comment: @Tim Slopeggio?

Comment: @It'sHEDLEY - for a moment I thought you meant sloppieggio, but yes, why not?